# TFS, search for work items assigned to me or unassigned

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS, and would like to search for all work items that are either assigned to @Me, or that are not assigned at all. Searching for unassigned can be done if you are using the operator "=" and just leave the value blank, but in this case I think I would need to use the operator "in" since I need to look for more than one criteria. The problem is, I can't leave it blank and also look for "@Me". Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an "or" instead of trying to do an "in".  If you have other clauses, like work item type, you'll want to group the assigned to clauses.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for